# How to disable date picker past date according to the another date picker selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

I have two date pickers. which are Start date and End date. How to disable End date picker's past dates respect to the start date picker  selected date.

**As a example.**
If I select 20th November 2019 in Start date date picker, I have to disable all the previous dates(past dates) in  End Date date picker.

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <lable>Select Start Date</lable>
    <input id="txtstartdate" />
    <lable>Select End Date</lable> 
    <input id="txtenddate" />
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```js
   $("#txtstartdate").datepicker({
            minDate: $("#txtstartdate").value,

            onSelect: function (date) {
                $("#txtenddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
            }
        });

        $("#txtenddate").datepicker({});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <lable>Select Start Date</lable>
    <input id="txtstartdate" />
   
    <lable>Select End Date</lable> 
    <input id="txtenddate" />
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```